# Previous row value added to the current row and so on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using version 2012.

I have this table with the data.

```
        create table #temp_metrics
        (
            id int identity(1,1)
            ,prev_total int not null default(0)
            ,added int not null default(0)
            ,total int not null default(0)
        )

        insert into #temp_metrics
        (
             added
        )
        values
        (
            10
        ),(20),(5),(15),(9)

        select * from #temp_metrics
```

I am expecting the output as below

[image]

Previous row total should be current row prev_total

Total should be the previous row total+added

I am using the below query

```
      ;WITH CTE AS (
                    SELECT
                        id
                        ,Total
                    from 
                        #temp_metrics
                    )
        SELECT
                prev.total  as prev_total 
                ,t.added
                ,prev.total +t.added  as total
        FROM 
            #temp_metrics t
            LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.id = t.id - 1
```

But looks like I am missing something.

How can I get the output as in the image format ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
Select ID
      ,Prev_Total = sum(Added) over (Order By ID) -Added
      ,Added
      ,totoal = sum(Added) over (Order By ID)
 From  #temp_metrics 
 Order By ID
```

Returns

```
ID  Prev_Total  Added   totoal
1   0           10      10
2   10          20      30
3   30          5       35
4   35          15      50
5   50          9       59
```

Comment: This answer would be useful to future readers if it had some explanation of why it worked.   I had to do quite a bit of research to find out why it wasn't producing the same "totoal" for every row.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using sum and lag

```
;with cte as (
select *, RunningTotal = sum(added) over(order by id) from #temp_metrics 
)
select *, lag(RunningTotal,1, 0) over(order by id) as Prev_total from cte
```